# Centering Not Possible On All Mobile Browsers - Normal Browser Works Superb

Tags: css, html, mobile, browser

Oddly I have a weird problem with centering divs for 
mobile browsers. Like my title says: normal pc browser 
work just fine - nada problemo =D but these mobile 
devices let my main content (under the button section)
stick to the left. I tried many things - looked for solutions
here on stackoverflow too - but the given tipps didn't 
help me so far ... the last thing i was able to center
was using jQuery - but I don't want to relay on that.

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<link href="css/configcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('pictures/Layout/Button/homeo.png','pictures/Layout/Button/grafiko.png','pictures/Layout/Button/webo.png','pictures/Layout/Button/reklamo.png','pictures/Layout/Button/fotoo.png','pictures/Layout/Button/videoo.png','pictures/Layout/Button/muziko.png')">
<div id="headbackground">
    <div id="headcontent">
      <div id="language"> <a href="index.html"><img src="pictures/tr.png" width="40" height="24" alt="tr"></a>
      <br><br>
      <a href="de/"><img src="pictures/de.png" width="40" height="24" alt="de"></a> 
      <br><br>
      <a href="en/"><img src="pictures/en.png" width="40" height="24" alt="en"></a>  
      </div> 
</div>
  <div id="buttons">
    <div id="navimiddle"><a href="/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('home','','pictures/Layout/Button/homeo.png',1)"><img src="pictures/Layout/Button/homeo.png" alt="homebutton" width="190" height="50" id="home"></a><a href="tr/grafik/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('grafik','','pictures/Layout/Button/grafiko.png',1)"><img src="pictures/Layout/Button/grafik.png" alt="grafikbutton" width="141" height="50" id="grafik"></a><a href="tr/web/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('web','','pictures/Layout/Button/webo.png',1)"><img src="pictures/Layout/Button/web.png" alt="webbutton" width="101" height="50" id="web"></a><a href="tr/reklam/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('reklam','','pictures/Layout/Button/reklamo.png',1)"><img src="pictures/Layout/Button/reklam.png" alt="reklambutton" width="159" height="50" id="reklam"></a><a href="tr/foto/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('foto','','pictures/Layout/Button/fotoo.png',1)"><img src="pictures/Layout/Button/foto.png" alt="fotobutton" width="108" height="50" id="foto"></a><a href="tr/video/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('video','','pictures/Layout/Button/videoo.png',1)"><img src="pictures/Layout/Button/video.png" width="125" height="50" id="video" alt="videobutton"></a><a href="tr/muzik/" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('muzik','','pictures/Layout/Button/muziko.png',1)"><img src="pictures/Layout/Button/muzik.png" alt="muzikbutton" width="200" height="50" id="muzik"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="contentbody">
<div id="contentup">
  <div id="contentuplayout"><center>
    <iframe width="950" height="370" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/E-dw03-s1vA?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </center>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contentdevider"></div>
<div id="contentmain">
<div id="mainrow1">
<span class="linkstyle2">    
<div class="smallarticel" >
  <div class="smallarticelpic"><a href="tr/grafik/"><span class="rollover"><img src="pictures/Grafik-Site/kurumsal-kimlik.png" width="270" height="150" alt="ambalaj">       </span></a>
  </div><hr>
  <strong><a href="tr/grafik/">GRAFiK TASARIM</a></strong>
  <hr>
  <p>Profesyonel ve Modern Grafik Tasar&#305;m</p>
  </div>  
  <div class="smallarticel2">
  <div class="smallarticelpic"><a href="tr/web/"><img src="pictures/Grafik-Site/webdesign.jpg" width="270" height="150" alt="ambalaj"></a>
  </div><hr>
  <strong><a href="tr/web/">WEB TASARIM</a></strong>
  <hr>
  <p>Profesyonel ve Modern Webtasar&#305;m
  </p>
</div>    
<div class="smallarticel">
  <div class="smallarticelpic"><a href="tr/foto/"><img src="pictures/fotograf-cekim.jpg" width="270" height="150" alt="ambalaj"></a>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <strong><a href="tr/foto/">FOTO&#286;RAF &Ccedil;EK&#304;M&#304;</a></strong>
  <hr>
  <p>Profesyonel St&uuml;dyo ve Outdoor &Ccedil;ekimleri</p>
</div>
</span>    
</div>
<div id="mainrow2">
<span class="linkstyle2">    
<div class="smallarticel">
  <div class="smallarticelpic"><a href="tr/reklam/"><img src="pictures/Reklam-Site/radio.jpg" width="270" height="150" alt="ambalaj"></a>
  </div><hr>
  <strong><a href="tr/reklam/">REKLAM AJANSI</a></strong>
  <hr>
  <p>Profesyonel Reklam Tasarim ve Jingle</p>
  </div>
  <div class="smallarticel2">
  <div class="smallarticelpic"><a href="tr/video/"><img src="pictures/video-prodüskiyon.jpg" width="270" height="150" alt="ambalaj"></a>
  </div><hr>
  <strong><a href="tr/video/">Video Prod&uuml;ksiyon</a></strong>
  <hr>
  <p>Profesyonel Video Prod&uuml;ksiyon ve Animasyon</p>
  </div>
  <div class="smallarticel">
  <div class="smallarticelpic"><a href="tr/muzik/"><img src="pictures/müzik-prodüksiyon.jpg" width="270" height="150" alt="ambalaj"></a>
  </div><hr>
  <strong><a href="tr/muzik/">M&uuml;zik Prod&uuml;ksiyon</a></strong>
  <hr>
  <p>&nbsp;Profesyonel M&uuml;zik Prod&uuml;ksiyon &nbsp; - Online Mastering ve Mixing -</p>
</div>
</span>
</div>
</div>  
<div class="placeholder"></div>    
</div>   
<div id="footer">
  <div id="footercontent">
    <span class="linkstyle1">
    <a href="tr/hakkimizda/">Hakk&#305;m&#305;zda</a> | <a href="tr/kariyer/">Kariyer</a> | <a href="tr/iletisim/">&#304;leti&#351;im</a> | <a href="tr/gizlilik/">Gizlilik</a></span>
    <div id="copyright">
    Can-Kat &copy; 2012
    </div>    
  </div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

AND THE STYLE/CSS : The problem is in the #contentbody the rest is 
centering just fine.

```
body {
   background-color:#FFF;
   margin-left:0px;
   margin-top:0px;
   margin-right:0px;
   font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

#headbackground {
    width:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background-color:#2E2E2E;

}

#headcontent {
    width:1000px;
    height:180px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-image:url(../media/Can-Kat%20Productions%20Logo%20-%20wordpress.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}

#language {
    width:40px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left:920px;
    margin-top:35px;
    display:none;
}

#buttons {
    width:1024px;
    height:50px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    color:#FFF;
    position:relative;
    font-size:20px;
}

#navimiddle
{
    width:1024px;
    height:50px;
    position:reltive;
    margin-top:4px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(../pictures/Layout/Button/leiste.png);
}

#contentbody {
    width:1000px;
    margin-top:-55px;
    margin-left:50%;
    left:-500px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#contentup {
    width:997px;
    background-image:url(../media/body_top.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}

#contentuplayout {
    width:960px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding-top:18px;
    position:relative;
}

#contentmain {
    width:902px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:-10px;
    position:relative;
}

#mainrow1 {
    width:902px;
    height:305px;
    position:relative;
}

#mainrow2 {
    width:902px;
    height:280px;
    margin-top:5px;
    position:relative;
}

#verticalrowleft {
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    color:#000;
    position:relative;
    float:left;     
}

#verticalrowright {
    width:295px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    border-left:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    min-width:1024px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#2E2E2E;
    float:left;
}

#footercontent {
    width:902px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    position:relative;
    color:#FFF;
}

#copyright {
    width:150px;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}

/* -------- Classes --------- */
.rollover {
    width:270px;
    background-image:url(../pictures/Layout/hover-zoom.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:transparent;
    margin:auto;
}

.smallarticel {
    width:280px;
    height:296px;
    background-color:#DDD;
    border:thin #333;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.smallarticel2 {
    width:280px;
    height:296px;
    margin-left:26px;
    margin-right:26px;
    background-color:#DDD;
    border:thin #333;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.smallarticelpic {
    width:270px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000;
    background-image:url(../pictures/Layout/hover-zoom.png);
}

.contentdevider {
    width:960px;
    height:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-image:url(../pictures/contentdevider.png);
    position:relative;
}

.placeholder { width:100%; height:30px; position:relative; float:left; }

.linkstyle1 A:link    {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}
.linkstyle1 A:visited {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}
.linkstyle1 A:active  {color:#FFF; text-decoration:none;}
.linkstyle1 A:hover   {
    color: #F0F0F0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.linkstyle2 A:link    {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
.linkstyle2 A:visited {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
.linkstyle2 A:active  {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}
.linkstyle2 A:hover   {color:#000; text-decoration:underline;}

img
{  border-style: none; }

#language img { border-radius:5px; }

.centertext { text-align:center; }

a.link{
    background:transparent url(a-bg.png) no-repeat -81px bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish for your content to be centred on a mobile device, you will probably need to add specific CSS for a mobile device. And instead of relying on pixel based sizes you will need to use percentages.

### Centre Content Mobile Device

```
#container {
    width: 100%
}

#content-container {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right:10%;
}
```

Of course you could rewrite your whole CSS to be responsive to screen sizes. Here is a quick example of how you go about doing it. http://jsfiddle.net/4LSmq/

### How Target Mobile Screens

```
// target small screens (mobile devices or small desktop windows)
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* CSS goes here */
}

/* high resolution screens */
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
         (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
         (min-resolution: 300dpi) {
  header { background-image: url(header-highres.png); }
}

/* low resolution screens */
@media (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
         (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
         (max-resolution: 299dpi) {
  header { background-image: url(header-lowres.png); } 
}
```

### Second Solution

Try changing

```
#contentbody {
    width:1000px;
    margin-top:-55px;
    margin-left:50%;
    left:-500px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```

to

```
#contentbody {
    width:1000px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```

Your mobile screen is less than 1000px so your margin set in percentage is relative to the screen width which is less than 1000px in this case. Example http://jsfiddle.net/R9rSx/

Also it is wise to add, change the width until you get the desired look

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
```

Comment: Thank you Michael for your response...
But if i do that my site wouldn't be nice on a
full hd monitor... it would be nice if we find
a solution for this kind of problem ... my other
websites work fine with these techniques ... its 
really just this website im doing right now

Comment: I see, I didn't totally understand what you meant without being able to see it. I've added a 2nd solution with example which I think is what your looking for... It may be worth thinking about optimising for mobile as the way things are going, far fewer people have full HD screens over mobile devices.

Comment: The centering problem is ok but now i got the problem, that #contentup - background-image is sticking to the top... -.- 
...could you please help me with this too? i tried a few things but it gets kinda streched and all things. would be very happy if we could get it done ... looking forward to your answer - thank you!

Comment: and my #headcontent is cut off ?? =S

Comment: ahhhh no need no need =D i got it ... i took off all floats ... this solved it! again thank you very much michael ... wish you a wonderful day!

Comment: viewport tipp was great too! i was kinda looking for it =D

Comment: That's no problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

What about using meta tags?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```